# Find out max and min value for a column based on other column condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a following table

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
    [RowID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , [Column1] BIGINT NOT NULL
    , [Column2] CHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , [Column3] CHAR(5) NOT NULL
    , [Amount]  NUMERIC(16, 4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000
    , [SequenceNumber] INT NOT NULL
    , [SequenceType] CHAR(1) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 50019.0000, 1, 'P');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 50021.0000, 2, 'P');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 50023.0000, 3, 'P');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 50025.0000, 4, 'P');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 50027.0000, 5, 'D');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 50029.0000, 6, 'D');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 50033.0000, 8, 'P');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 50035.0000, 9, 'D');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 2754246.0000, 10, 'P');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 2660870.0000, 11, 'P');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 7938347.0000, 12, 'D');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00963', 7951196.0000, 13, 'D');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00964', 2660870.0000, 11, 'P');
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1, '62546J307', '00964', 7938347.0000, 12, 'D');

SELECT * FROM #Table1;

DROP TABLE #Table1
```

**Table rows**

[image]

I need to find out max and min Amount based on column "SequenceType" value for column "Column1", "Column2" and "Column3".

Output columns:
Column1, Column2, Column3, MaxAmountForSeqTypeP, MinAmountForSeqTypeP, MaxAmountForSeqTypeD, MinAmountForSeqTypeP

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: [I downvote because... No own attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Please follow the link, to find, what you should have done...

Comment: I updated "Expected output" image

Comment: Saaif, read [I downvote because - images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)... Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056). You are providing sample data and a consumable table. That's good!. The point is: You are expecting help from foreign strangers... SO is not a *please do my (home?)work* platform...

Comment: Honestly, people should stop giving answers to such low-effort questions. SQL pivot/crosstab questions are asked 50+ times a day and a large portion of them have invested little to no effort into solving their questions. Yet people still give (the same) answers over and over.

Comment: I agree, it is a common problem and after seeing answer, i feel like i did not put enough effort to solve this problem. I will keep in mind for my next question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select Column1, Column2, Column3, 
    max(case when SequenceType = 'P' then amount else null end) MaxP, 
    min(case when SequenceType = 'P' then amount else null end) MinP,
    max(case when SequenceType = 'D' then amount else null end) MaxD, 
    min(case when SequenceType = 'D' then amount else null end) MinD
from Table1
group by Column1, Column2, Column3
```

Or this might be faster:

```
;with cte as (
     select Column1, Column2, Column3, 
         case when SequenceType = 'P' then amount else null end P,
         case when SequenceType = 'D' then amount else null end D
     from Table1
)
select Column1, Column2, Column3, Max(P) MaxP, Min(P) MinP, Max(D) MaxD, MIn(D) MinD
from cte
group by Column1, Column2, Column3
```

Comment: I will also go with this solution ... (As @ZLK mentioned, this should fairly available solution over SO)

Comment: @MJH, thanks for your answer.I am wondering why didn't i think this way to find out my expected output and i agree. I think, experience meters sometime!

Comment: @Saaif: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.